Optimize performance of SubstrateInterface.decode_scale
I am using Python's substrate interface to look at extrinsic for a particular block of a Substrate-based blockchain. However, the decode_scale method is very slow: it takes about 1 second for 500 extrinsics (about 1 million bytes total). A simple baseline with binascii is 100-1000x faster, although it doesn't do the scale codec part of the decoding.
Current code:
substrate = SubstrateInterface(url="ws://localhost:9944")
...
async with session.post("http://localhost:9944", json=payload) as resp:
    res = await resp.json()
    for hex_extrinsic in res['result']:
        decoded = substrate.decode_scale("Extrinsic", hex_extrinsic)
        ... # process decoded

Is there a way to speed this up? Such as a performance-optimized library for this.
